# Event listener for foreach loop completion

Tags: javascript, html

so what I have right now is

```
window.addEventListener('load', fetchInfo)

function fetchInfo() {
    const tableRows = //an array of results

    tableRows.forEach((row) => {
        const rowId = //get the id of each row
        fetch(...) //fetch some stuff using the id
            .then(() => {
                //do some stuff
                return rowId;
            })
            .then((id) => {
                //do some stuff
                }
            })
    })
}
```

basically using rowId to fetch information and populate each table row, so this happens a few times, the table maxes out at 10 rows so max 10 fetches

I want to have an event listener to see when all the fetching is done, aka when the table is completely done loading. How should I go about that?

Edit: these fetches are api requests so they take a few seconds to respond. I've tried using `Promise.all(tableRows.map(row) =>` and it returned results before the api could respond. So in the end, it still doesn't really detect when does the table actually finish loading information.

Comment: You probably shouldn't call your actual function `fetch`. You may run into some errors. As to your question why not use a variable, and increase it every row, and check it before doing another fetch?

Comment: ok I will change that

Comment: Use a counter variable, increment it by 1 for each fetch that has finished - and then check if it matches the number of table rows you got ...?

Comment: but the number of rows is dynamic, the only thing set in stone is that it will max out at 10

Comment: Maybe `Promise.all`?

Comment: _"but the number of rows is dynamic"_ - yes, so? You have an _array_ of rows that you are looping over - and an array has a `length` property.

Comment: Why can't your API send 10 rows of data? It would save you this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the suggestion in the comments `length` was indeed the way, however that would only be half of the solution. Because the key point here is that I want to know whether or not the table has been fully populated with requested information.

Tried `Promise.all` and `map()` and didn't work out because as stated in my edit, these will return when the fetch was called, when the fetch was still pending, and doesn't really care if the fetch was a 200 OK, which was what I needed.

So the solution was to use `response.status`

```
function fetchInfo() {
    const tableRows = ...
    let successFetch = 0;

    tableRows.forEach((row) => {
        fetch(...)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    successFetch = successFetch + 1
                }
                if (successFetch == tableRows.length) {
                    //this point here was exactly what I needed
                }
                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => {
                ...
            })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise.all:

```
async function fetchInfo() {
    const tableRows = //an array of results
    const results = await Promise.all(tableRows.map(row => fetch(...))
    console.log(results)
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and sadly it doesn't really serve my purpose. The console log just returned the result before the table was loaded. I think this is because this tracks all the fetches as been sent off. But because these fetches in the backend are API calls and need some time to respond, the fetches are still pending while this promise all map already returned results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all promises to complete

```
Promise.all(
    tableRows.map((row) => {
        return fetch(...).then(() => {
            return rowId;
        })
    })
).then((results) => {
    console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: Your answer might be *correct* and solves the OP's issue, but the problem with your answer is that you didn't provide any explanation on why you chose to have such solution. Please avoid *code only* answers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).